# Where can I ask this question about cell phone repair/cleaning or general micro-USB port cleaning?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

My question is about a dumb cell phone, but it's also about a micro-USB port.

My MIL died. Went through her stuff and found an older cell phone, the dumb kind with a slide out keyboard. I'd like to donate it to a women's shelter. I'm sure it would work if I could charge it, but I can't get the cord completely into the micro-USB port because of gunk built up in there (probably hair spray and baby powder). Toothpick only got part out. I have a few questions about how I might clean it.

Is there a Stack Exchange site that might apply to cell phone hardware repair/cleaning (dumb or smartphone) or that might be able to help with cleaning micro-USB ports regardless of whatever electronic device they're on?

Comment: Already asked and answered... https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/q/9270/6973